# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while trying to run ST312_TestMain class

Tags: java, ibm-sterling

I am trying to call "getOrderList" from the ST312_TestMain class. I am getting the java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError for the below mentioned class.

```
package com.Main;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import com.yantra.ycp.core.YCPContext;
import com.Main.XMLUtil;
import com.Main.SterlingUtil;

public class ST312_TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String ServiceName = "getOrderList";
        String sServiceFlag = "N";
        Document dTemplate = null;
        //ServiceName = "SendDN";
        //sServiceFlag = "Y";
        Document inputXML=null;
        inputXML = XMLUtil.getDocument("<Order OrderHeaderKey='201407181105267340509' />");
        //inputXML = XMLUtil.getXmlFromFile("src/Test.xml");
        dTemplate = XMLUtil.getDocument("<Order OrderHeaderKey='' OrderNo=''/>");
        if (args.length == 3) {
            ServiceName = args[0];
            sServiceFlag = args[1].equals("Y") ? "Y" : "N";
            inputXML = XMLUtil.getXmlFromFile(args[2]);
        } else {
            System.out
            .println("Usage: TestMain <API/Service Name> <API/Service(N/Y)> <Input XML File>");
            System.out
            .println("No Input received using preset XML to call preset Service");
            System.out.println("Service Name=" + ServiceName);
        }
        ***YCPContext env = new YCPContext("admin", "admin");***
        System.out.println("Input XML \n" + XMLUtil.getXmlString(inputXML));

        try {           
            Document outputXML = null;
            if ("Y".equals(sServiceFlag)) {
                outputXML = SterlingUtil.callService(env, inputXML, ServiceName, null);
            } else {
                outputXML = SterlingUtil.callAPI(env, inputXML, ServiceName, dTemplate);
            }

            env.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Service Invocation Failed");
        }

    }

}
```

The exception is as follows:

```
Usage: TestMain <API/Service Name> <API/Service(N/Y)> <Input XML File>
No Input received using preset XML to call preset Service
Service Name=getOrderList
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.yantra.ycp.core.YCPContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.util.frame.Manager.getProperty(Manager.java:1365)
    at com.yantra.yfc.util.YFCConfigurator.setStandalone(YFCConfigurator.java:37)
    at com.yantra.yfs.core.YFSSystem.init(YFSSystem.java:62)
    at com.yantra.yfs.core.YFSSystem.<clinit>(YFSSystem.java:47)
    at com.yantra.ycp.core.YCPContext.<init>(YCPContext.java:288)
    at com.yantra.ycp.core.YCPContext.<init>(YCPContext.java:276)
    at com.Main.ST312_TestMain.main(ST312_TestMain.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.util.frame.log.base.SCILogBaseConfig.doConfigure(SCILogBaseConfig.java:35)
    at com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.util.frame.log.LogService.<clinit>(LogService.java:110)
    ... 7 more
```

Please help me on this problem, since I am not sure how to handle the YCPContext object. ("YCPContext env = new YCPContext("admin", "admin");"). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post `SCILogBaseConfig` source code and mark 35th line

Answer (score 0):

Request support from IBM about this.

No matter what mistakes you may have made configuring it (if any), the Sterling code should not be throwing an NPE at you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in local using main() method, then you should comment all the lines where you are using environment varilable. For your code its ***env*** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wouldn't have added the database driver jars to your project build path... For e.g.
For DB2 database, db2jcc.jar has to be added 
For Oracle database, ojdbc.jar has to be added